# iTerm can't delete directories

Tags: terminal, iterm

I just started working with iTerm an I've been playing around, creating folders and files and such. Now I want to get rid of those test folders. I used `rmdir`, `rm -r` and all of those commands and I successfully emptied the folders, but they still show up in my main folder.
When I try to delete them, it says the folders aren't empty, even though they are.

Does anybody know how to fix this? I just want to clean up my main folder. :(
Thanks in advance.

I tried various delete commands.

Comment: Did you try `rm -rf <folder>`, relaunch Finder, or restart system?

Comment: The folders likely contain hidden files (in unix-land, which Mac OS X is part of that means files where the names start with a `.` like `.config` or such). Also: iTerm isn't really doing much other than displaying text and taking input, the thing that takes and executes your commands is a shell (which is zsh by default on Mac OS X).

Comment: @Mr.Míng i tired rm -rf <folder> and have restarted my Mac since then...

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks for the definition. I'm still getting my vocab mixed up. Is there a way to delete those hidden files as well?